# Get ACF value in external jQuery document

Tags: jquery, advanced-custom-fields, variables

I'm trying to get the value of an Advanced Custom Fields *select list* in an external jQuery document, in order to apply some conditions to it.

I looked for an answer and found only solution involving the use of  tags inside the page, which I want to avoid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is not entirely clear, but it looks like you are in need of [`wp_localize_script`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_localize_script/), which allows you to pass variables from PHP to a script. You would use it like this (example with two fields):

```
add_action ('wp_enqueue_scripts','wpse244551_add_field');
function wpse244551_add_field () {
  $my_field = array ();
  $my_field[] = array (field1 => get_field ('field1'));
  $my_field[] = array (field2 => get_field ('field2'));
  wp_localize_script ('my-script', 'MyFields', $my_field);
  }
```

Now, in the script you have registered with the handle `my-script` you can access the variable with `MyFields.field1` and `MyFields.field2`.