# Get with jQuery the value of an ACF field

Tags: jquery, advanced-custom-fields, wp-enqueue-script, wp-localize-script

I'm trying to store in a variable the content of an ACF field so that later on I can use it in a jQuery function using the plugin "Simple Custom CSS and JS".

I found what I thought was the answer in the following link [Get ACF value in external jQuery document](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/244551/get-acf-value-in-external-jquery-document) but I'm getting an error inside the console saying **"Uncaught ReferenceError: MyFields is not defined"**.

This is my PHP code:

```
add_action ('wp_enqueue_scripts','wpse244551_add_field');

function wpse244551_add_field () {
  $my_field = array ();
  $my_field[] = array ('field1' => get_field ('variable_product_html'));
  wp_localize_script ('myScript', 'MyFields', $my_field);
}
```

This is my jQuery code (*Note: I'm using the Simple Custom CSS and JS to write my code*):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ){
    
    function myScript() {
        var phpValue = MyFields.field1;
        console.log(phpValue);
    }
  
    myScript();

});
```

Comment: When using `wp_localize_script` the script must also be registered with `wp_register_script` or `wp_enqueue_script`.

Comment: @JörnLund Thanks for your comments, based on the code I copy from another post they are registering the PHP function with the `wp_enqueue_script` using the `add_action()`, could you be more specific with your answer? do I need to change this to the name of the script or add another `wp_enqueue_script` for the jQuery function?

Comment: Shortly spoken: Every `wp_localize_script('some-script-handle', ...)` needs a `wp_enqueue_script('some-script-handle', 'some-script-url.js', ...)` first. Your code does either not call it, or it's using a script handle, that was not registered before. 
This article explains the concept quite well: https://pippinsplugins.com/use-wp_localize_script-it-is-awesome/